# How to convert software into a DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, sdk

I have a software which provides some functionality which is written in C++ language visual studio. I want to use this into my asp.net web application which is written in C#. So I decided to convert the software into DLL, so that I can include the DLL in my web application to use the functionality.

How to convert the software into a DLL?
Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: It seems that you're using at least some of that terminology incorrectly, which makes your question confusing.  Please consider revising it so it's clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: is it possible to convert sdk into dll?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit ...

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin: I have revised my question, please have a look into this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building solution in VS. It will create dll in Obj folder of solution.

Or

If this doesn't works, try creating a PCL and build it and you will get your desired dll.